# Memory leak seemingly caused by VBS program

Tags: sql-server, windows, vbscript, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server

It seems one of our VBS programs causes memory leak. Could anyone give any advice for me to avoid it?

I have a VBS program in Server-A. The first part of the VBS program selects just one record from Server-B (SQL Server) and decide whether it executes the following codes or quits by the value of one column of the record. It is executed by a scheduled task at Server-A that runs every one minute.

Though the program monitors the table every one minute, it quits just after checking the table values most of the times and proceed to the following process only once or twice a month. However, the amount of Free Memory of the Server-A decreases dramatically as you can see in the attached image.

The function below is the one called at the first part of the VBS program. If the return code is 0, it quits.

If anyone give us any advice, I would greatly appreciate it.

Image: Free Memory Usage (Green = Free Memory) (Aug 12 - Aug 27)
[image]

```vb
Dim DestDWHServer
(*snip*)

Call Main

'**************************************
    Main  
'**************************************
Sub Main

    'Get the name of the DBserver (DEV/QA/PROD)
    Call subSetDestDWHServer 

    'Check the order from the user
    if fncCTLCheck_Update() = 0 then Exit Sub

    (*snip*)

End Sub

'**************************************
    Check the Order from Users 
'**************************************
Function fncCTLCheck_Update()

    dim ret,flgOrder,cn,sSQLSelect,sSQLUpdate,sSvr,sDB,sCn,cmd,rs
    '
    ret = 0
    '
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    sSvr = DestDWHServer
    sDB = "DB_A"
    '
    sCn = "XXXXXXXXXXX" 'ConnectionString
    cn.ConnectionString = sCn
    cn.Open
    '
    sSQLSelect= "SELECT [FLG_ORDER], [STATUS_T] FROM [DB_A].[dbo].
    [T_CTL_TASK] WHERE [TASK_ID] = 1"
    '
    Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    cmd.ActiveConnection = cn
    cmd.CommandText = sSQLSelect
    '
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    rs.Open cmd
    flgOrder = rs.Fields("FLG_ORDER").Value
    '
    rs.Close
    '
    If flgOrder = 0 then
        ret = 0
    Else    
        ret = 1
        sSQLUpdate = "UPDATE [DB_A].[dbo].[T_CTL_TASK] set [FLG_ORDER]=0, 
    [STATUS_T]=1, [LAST_START_DTM] = getdate() WHERE [TASK_ID] = 1"
        cmd.CommandText = sSQLUpdate 
        cmd.Execute
    End If
    cn.Close
    set cmd = nothing
    set cn = nothing
    '
    fncCTLCheck_Update = ret
    '
End Function

'**************************************
    Get the server name 
'**************************************
Sub subSetDestDWHServer
    Dim obj
    Dim HostName
    Set obj = CreateObject("WScript.Network")

    HostName=obj.ComputerName
    Set obj = Nothing

    select case HostName
        case "ServerA_DEV"
            DestDWHServer = "ServerB_DEV"
        case "ServerA_QA"
            DestDWHServer = "ServerB_QA"
        case "ServerA_PROD"
            DestDWHServer = "ServerB_PROD"
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: How do you know that it is this script that claims the memory? And where does the DestDWHServer variable come from?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I realized that this was the cause because the Free Memory stopped decreasing while I disabled the task and monitored.  DestDWHServer is defined and given the value just before the function above is called. It stores the name of Server-B.

Comment: SQL Server will use as much memory as you allow it for caching. Are these new rows being selected/updated every time?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Just one row is registered in the table in Server-B and retrieved from Server-A every time, but updated only once or twice a month. Server-A monitors the order from the user who update FLG_ORDER column of T_CTL_TASK table. Memory leak occurs at Server-A.

Comment: You set nothing cmd and cn. Try also rs for completeness.

Comment: Thanks Daniel! I'll try it.

Comment: If this is most of the code and nothing else interacts with the VBS, I don't understand why you wouldn't just run this in a SQL Agent Job. But I guess the *snip* must do something special. You don't have any `msgbox` in here do you? Do you by any change have a bunch of orphan csript or wscript processes floating around? You should be able to open task manager and identify which particular process in there is using this memory. Is the SQL Server in the same box that the VBScript runs on?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Once VBS find the users' order in the retrieved record, it runs following codes which downloads data to the files in Server-A via a third party tool and copy the files from Server-A to Server-B. Once files reached Server-B, they are imported by SSIS package kicked by Agent Job. Actually all the processes was in Server-B before, but because Server-B runs Windows 2003 and the new version of DL tool didn't work on 2003, we divided it into two parts and moved DL part to Server-A (Win2012).